# Using a BoxWhiskerChart as a plot marker in ListPlot

Tags: charts

I want to plot the means of several data sets, but instead of using a point I would like to use a box-and-whisker plot to represent the full data set. Here is what I mean (with some toy data):

```
a = {1.7610325845854935, 1.4482381483503182, 1.262594767165387, 2.2720460660207409};
b = {2.1844741151332943, 3.5175853047673318, 3.5245233201347768, 2.0819498353445609};
c = {1.3755036246747516, 1.6169073661736904, 2.3472569940481094, 2.9457474653314475};
dat = {a, b, c};
ListPlot[Table[Mean[dat[[i]]], {i, Length[dat]}], 
    PlotStyle -> PointSize -> Large, PlotRange -> Full]
```

I would like to set the `PlotMarkers` in a way that the first marker is a box-and-whisker of `a`, the second a box-and-whisker plot of `b`, and so on.

Thank you in advance for any help you can offer!

Comment: Like this: `BoxWhiskerChart[dat, {"Mean", {"MedianMarker", None}}, Prolog -> {ColorData[97, 1], Line[Transpose[{Range[3], Mean /@ dat}]]}]`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using `Show[]` to combine your graph with the `BoxWhiskerChart[]` (update: incorporated comment)

```
a = {1.7610325845854935, 1.4482381483503182, 1.262594767165387, 2.2720460660207409};
b = {2.1844741151332943, 3.5175853047673318, 3.5245233201347768, 2.0819498353445609};
c = {1.3755036246747516, 1.6169073661736904, 2.3472569940481094, 2.9457474653314475};
dat = {a, b, c};

Show[
 BoxWhiskerChart[dat, {"Mean", {"MedianMarker", None}}],
 ListLinePlot[Mean /@ dat, PlotRange -> Full]
 ]
```

[image]

Comment: `ListLinePlot[Mean /@ dat, PlotRange -> Full]` is sufficient.

Answer (score 7):

**Update 3:**  From the function `` Charting`iBoxWhiskerChart `` we get the full list of built-in settings for `Joined`:

```
Grid[{{Automatic | All | True | 
     "Median", {{Mean[#1[[1]]], Quantile[#2, 0.5`]} &}},
   {"Mean", {{Mean[#1[[1]]], Mean[#2]} &}},
   {"Max", {{Mean[#1[[1]]], Max[#2]} &}},
   {"Min", {{Mean[#1[[1]]], Min[#2]} &}},
   {"LowerQuartile", {{Mean[#1[[1]]], Quantile[#2, 0.25`]} &}},
   {"UpperQuartile", {{Mean[#1[[1]]], Quantile[#2, 0.75`]} &}},
   {None | False, {}}}, Dividers -> All] // 
 Style[#, 20, ShowStringCharacters -> True] &
```

[image]

**Update 2:** It also turns out that, in both `BoxWhiskerChart` and `DistributionChart`, the option `Joined` has a few built-in settings such as `"Mean","Min", "Max", "Median"` (in addition to arbitrary pure functions shown in the original answer.)

```
SeedRandom[1]
data = RandomVariate[LogNormalDistribution[1, .5], {10, 100}];

Row[BoxWhiskerChart[data, Joined -> #, 
      PlotLabel -> Style[Row[{"Joined  -> ", "\"", #, "\""}], 16, "Panel"], 
      ChartStyle -> "Pastel", ImageSize -> 250] /. l : Line[__] :> {#2, Thick, l} & @@@ 
   Transpose[{{"Min", "Mean", "Median", "Max"}, {Red, Green, Blue, Orange}}]]
```

[image]

It seems that only a single line can be produced using `Joined`. To get multiple lines, we can  `Show` multiple charts with different `Joined` settings:

```
colors = {Red, Green, Blue, Orange};
i = 1; 
Show[BoxWhiskerChart[data, Joined -> #, 
     ChartBaseStyle -> {EdgeForm[Opacity[.1]], FaceForm[]}, 
     ChartStyle -> "Pastel"] & /@ {"Min", "Max", "Mean", "Median"}] /. 
 l_Line :> {colors[[i++]], Thick, l}
```

[image]

Using `DistributionChart` in place of `BoxWhiskerChart` above we get

[image]

and

[image]

**Update:** A pure function setting for `Joined` also works for `BarChart`. Such functions apply to the list of horizontal and vertical ranges `{{xmin, xmax}, {ymin, ymax}}` of the rectangles:

```
BarChart[{{3, 3, 4, 1}, 2 + {3, 3, 4, 1}}, Joined -> (Mean /@ # & )] /. 
 l : Line[x_ /; (x[[1, 2]] =!= 0.)] :> {Red, Thick, l}
```

[image]

```
BarChart[{{3, 3, 4, 1}, 2 + {3, 3, 4, 1}}, Joined -> (Max /@ # & )] /. 
 l : Line[x_ /; (x[[1, 2]] =!= 0.)] :> {Red, Thick, l}
```

[image]

**Original Answer:**

**BoxWhiskerChart with the option Joined**

It turns out that, in `BoxWhiskerChart`, functions can be used as the setting for the option `Joined` and the setting `(Mean[#2] &)` gives the desired result without having to use `ListLinePlot`:

```
BoxWhiskerChart[{a, b, c}, "Mean", Joined -> (Mean[#2] &), ChartStyle -> "Pastel"]
```

[image]

If desired, post-process to style the line

```
BoxWhiskerChart[{a, b, c}, "Mean", Joined -> (Mean[#2] &), ChartStyle -> "Pastel"] /. 
  l : Line[__] :> {Red, Thick, l}
```

[image]

Another example:

```
SeedRandom[1]
data = RandomVariate[NormalDistribution[], {10, 100}];

BoxWhiskerChart[data, "Mean", Joined -> (Mean[#2] &), ChartStyle -> "Pastel"] /. 
  l : Line[__] :> {Red, Thick, l}
```

[image]

**DistributionChart with the option Joined**

`Joined` works the same way in `DistributionChart`.

```
DistributionChart[{a, b, c},  Joined -> (Mean[#2] &), 
  ChartElementFunction -> "PointDensity", ChartStyle -> "Pastel"] /. 
 l : Line[__] :> {Red, Thick, l}
```

[image]

```
DistributionChart[data,  Joined -> (Mean[#2] &), 
  ChartElementFunction -> "PointDensity", ChartStyle -> "Pastel"] /. 
 l : Line[__] :> {Red, Thick, l}
```

[image]

Comment: How nice! How did you discover this?

Comment: @J.M. , pure luck. The docs mention only `Automatic` and `True` as the settings for `Joined`. I accidentally discovered that  `All` also works. Tried `Joined -> (Print[{##}] &)` and noticed that it returns `{{{xmin, xmax}, {ymin, ymax}}, data}` indicating that `Joined` is passed this information. So, tried different functions `Median[#2]&`, `Quantile[#2, .9]&` , `Mean[#2]&` and all worked.

Comment: I wonder how many more gems can be uncovered just by sticking `Print[{##}] &` at appropriate positions... :) good work!